# SELECT inside INSERT multiple rows from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my Code :

```
INSERT INTO CAR_RENTAL.billing
(NO_OF_DAYS,BILL_DATE,DAILY_RENT,ADVANCE,C_NAME,RENTAL_ID,C_CARD,VIN)
VALUES
(7,'2016-01-12',500,1000,
(select c_name from car_rental.customer where c_id=11),
(select rental_id from car_rental.company where rental_id=1),
(select c_card from car_rental.customer where c_id=11),'aud-890'),

(7,'2016-02-12',5000,12000,
(select c_name from car_rental.customer where c_id=12),
(select rental_id from car_rental.company where rental_id=2),
(select c_card from car_rental.customer where c_id=12),'ben-389'),
```

When I run this in MYSQL, it works perfectly fine.
But when I try to run this in PhPMyAdmin, it gives an error.

I found various solutions on this site, but all of them were either for a single table or from a single table. But none for the type i am looking for.

Sorry if its a repost.

Comment: `it gives an error` You think we can predict errors here? OR may be you tell us what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Just using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO CAR_RENTAL.billing(NO_OF_DAYS, BILL_DATE, DAILY_RENT, ADVANCE, C_NAME, RENTAL_ID, C_CARD, VIN)
    select 7, '2016-01-12', 500, 1000, c.c_name, co.rental_id, c.c_card, 'aud-890'
    from car_rental.customer c cross join
         car_rental.company co
    where c.c_id = 11 and co.rental_id = 1;
```

You can do both in one query as;

```
INSERT INTO CAR_RENTAL.billing(NO_OF_DAYS, BILL_DATE, DAILY_RENT, ADVANCE, C_NAME, RENTAL_ID, C_CARD, VIN)
    select 7, '2016-01-12', 500, 1000, c.c_name, co.rental_id, c.c_card, 
           (case when c.c_id = 11 then 'aud-890' else 'ben-389' end)
    from car_rental.customer c cross join
         car_rental.company co
    where (c.c_id = 11 and co.rental_id = 1) or
          (c.c_id = 12 and co.rental_id = 2)
```

Comment: It is complicated for Phpmyadmin. Isnt there a easy way like in MySql ?

Comment: @dharmil007 . . . I don't understand your comment.  These seem pretty easy to me.